# What does the pad-osd.css file do?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I found a `pad-osd.css` file in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`. May I know which GDM widget is it used to style? It's contents are shown below.

```
.Leader {
    stroke-width: .5 !important;
    stroke: #535353;
    fill: none !important;
}

.Button {
    stroke-width: .25;
    stroke: #ededed;
    fill: #ededed;
}

.Ring {
    stroke-width: .5 !important;
    stroke: #535353 !important;
    fill: none !important;
}

.Label {
    stroke: none !important;
    stroke-width: .1 !important;
    font-size: .1 !important;
    fill: transparent !important;
}

.TouchStrip, .TouchRing {
    stroke-width: .1 !important;
    stroke: #ededed !important;
    fill: #535353 !important;
}
```

Comment: I would say that is some css for a browser or electron app. I've never encountered those "!important" directives within the GDM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSD is usually stand for *On Screen Display*. There is a [CSS property for it](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#GTK-STYLE-CLASS-OSD:CAPS).

This CSS file is loaded by GNOME Shell to extend properties of `DrawingArea` - see [search results in Debian's source code](https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-shell/3.34.3-1/js/ui/padOsd.js/?hl=298#L298).

> The DrawingArea widget is a blank window that gives you the freedom to create any graphic you desire.
>   [see [GNOME Developer Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-drawingarea.html.en) for details]